# Can't compile Play project from Makefile

Tags: playframework, makefile

I'm trying to compile my Play Framework project using GNU Make (3.81).

Here is my simple Makefile:

```
all:
        play compile
```

After running "make" I get the following error:

```
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Detailed error message:

```
$ play last:

[info] Loading project definition from /home/sergey/wrk/my/site/project
[info] Set current project to site (in build     file:/home/sergey/wrk/my/site/)
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sergey/wrk/my/site/project
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] Initially invalidated: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
[info] Set current project to site (in build file:/home/sergey/wrk/my/site/)
```

But when I'm doing the same from the shell:

```
$ play compile
```

... everything works fine.

I tried to pass "-Xmx 1024m" to play - didn't help.

System info:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with all updates installed
- Oracle JDK 1.6.0_45

Why doesn't my Makefile work as expected?

Comment: Did you "use 'last' for the full log"?

Comment: Good point. I added 'play last' output to the original message.